# What would be an optimal way to rewrite this into something simple

Tags: c++, function

User enters a number ex, 7. This then returns all the multiples of that number up till 1000. X is user input. I have if  / else if for each number. Would there be a different way to do this?

```
void printSeries()
{


if (x == 0)
{
    cout << "Closing program" << endl;


}


else if (x == 1)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 1 == 0)

        {

            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;

        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 2)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 2 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 3)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 3 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 4)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 4 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 5)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 5 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 6)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 6 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 7)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 7 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 8)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 8 == 0)

        {
            cout << "[" << x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
else if (x == 9)
{
    cout << "Printing numbers divisible by " << x << " between " << x << " and 1000" << endl;
    while (x <= 1000)

    {

        while (x % 9 == 0)

        {
            cout << "["<< x << "] ";
            break;
        }
        x++;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: numbers divisible by x are also multiples of x. can't u use that relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cin >> x;

int counter = 1;
while ((x>0) && (true))
{
  int multiple = x* counter;
  if (multiple > 1000) break;
  cout << multiple; 
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly. It does what it needs to do and is alot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straight-forward using a `for` loop, as this manages your 'counting' variable nicely:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int x = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a number (greater than 0): ";
    cin >> x;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; x * i < 1000; ++i)
        cout << '\n' << x * i; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int x = 0;

    std::cout << "Please input number: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    for (int i = 0; x*i < 1000; i++) {
        std::cout << "[" << x*i << "]" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```